# wordpress - Unable to see the pages in web site

Tags: html, wordpress

I was able to edit pages in wordpress dashboard, but when I was trying to look the pages through browser nothing is displayed.

Nothing is working except the home page.

I tried installing another theme but in all the themes only home page was working fine.

Comment: After publishing a page, can you click "View page"? If so, does the page load correctly? If that is the case, you may just need to include the page in your menu.

Comment: Page doesn't load even after clicking View Page

Comment: Does it return 404 Not Found?

Comment: This is what i see in firefox browser:                                  http://localhost/wordpress/about-us/?preview=true&preview_id=29&preview_nonce=e54c0a5a4f            along with that i see the below text displayed in firefox browser     Whoops! The page could not be found. Try giving it another chance below.

Comment: Nag, unfortunately since you are on a localhost install I am unable to see the page. Do you have a public facing version anywhere?

Comment: No Ryan I don't have any public version.I am just learning how to work on wordpress

Comment: I have changed permalinks to default.It was working fine.Again I changed it to custom with /%postname%/, now it throws the 404 error again   why is this happening?

Comment: Do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled on your server? And just to check, what kind of server are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked around at the Wordpress forums? Maybe this page ? http://wordpress.org/support/topic/page-not-found-39

Have you changed your site permissions (e.g via FTP) Sometimes having specific site permissions may cause your page not to show.

Do you have the most updated version of Wordpress?

Comment: I have changed permalinks to default.It was working fine.Again I changed it to custom with /%postname%/, now it throws the 404 error again   why is this happening?